# The form in my pop-pup window fails to submit the inserted data in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, forms, magnific-popup

I'm trying to submit data using a pop-pup form but my submit button just closes the windows instead of saving all the data into my data base.

Everything seems to be in order but I have the impression that the form cannot read the lines of code contained in my controller

Here my codes

```html
    <div class="modal" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
         aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title"><b>ADD A NEW CLIENT</b></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <i data-feather="x"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="{{ route('finance.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <label>Select an existing user from the database. </label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-5">
                                <select id="Clients" class="choices form-select" title="Selectionner"
                                        name="user_id">
                                    <optgroup label="{{ count($Users) }} clients retrouvés">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>-- choisir --</option>
                                        @foreach($Users as $User)
                                            <option value="{{ $User->id }}">{{ $User->fullname }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <label>Profession</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="choices form-select" title="Selectionner"
                                        name="profession_id">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>-- choisir --</option>
                                    @foreach($Professions as $Profession)
                                        <option value="{{ $Profession->id }}">{{ $Profession->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <label>Phone</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="+243 " class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <label>NID Type</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="nid_type" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <label>NID Photocopy</label>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <img id="outputs" style="width:45px;background-color: whitesmoke;
                                        border:1px solid #bbb;height:45px;border-radius: 2px" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-xs-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-file">
                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                                function previewImg(event) {
                                                    var outputs = document.getElementById('outputs');
                                                    outputs.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                                                }
                                            </script>
                                            <input type="file" name="nid_photocopie" accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg"
                                                   class="form-control" id="clientImges"
                                                   onchange="return previewImg(event)">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <label>Profile Image</label>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <img id="output" style="width:50px;height:50px;border-radius: 50px " >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-file">
                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                                function previewImage(event) {
                                                    var output = document.getElementById('output');
                                                    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                                                }
                                            </script>
                                            <input type="file" name="image" accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg"
                                                   class="form-file-input" id="clientImgz"
                                                   onchange="return previewImage(event)">
                                            <label class="form-file-label" for="clientImgz">
                                                <span class="form-file-text">Choose image...</span>
                                                <span class="form-file-button "><i data-feather="upload"></i></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    <i class="bx bx-x d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                                    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Close</span>
                                </button>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary ml-1" >
                                    <i class="bx bx-check d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                                    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Submit</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

HERE IS MY CONTROLLER

```html
public function storeProfile(Request $request)
    {
    $this->validate($request, [
    'user_id' => 'required',
    'profession_id'=> 'required',
    'nid_type'=> 'required',
    'nid_photocopie'=> 'required',
    ]);

    $slug = str_slug($request['fullname']);
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $image3 = $request->file('nid_photocopie');

    //INSERTS PROFILE IMAGE
    if (isset($image))
    {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $currentData = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
    $fileToStore = $slug .'-'. $currentData .'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    if(!file_exists('uploads/MicroCredit/ClientImage'))
    {
    mkdir('uploads/ClientImage', 0777 , true);
    }
    $image->move('uploads/ClientImage',$fileToStore);

    }
    else {
    $fileToStore = 'default.png';
    }

    //INSERT ID PHOTOCOPIE
    if (isset($image3))
    {
    $image3 = $request->file('nid_photocopie');
    $currentData = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
    $IdToStore = $slug .'-'. $currentData .'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image3->getClientOriginalExtension();
    if(!file_exists('uploads/MicroCredit/IDs'))
    {
    mkdir('uploads/IDs', 0777 , true);
    }
    $image3->move('uploads/IDs',$IdToStore);
    }
    else {
    $IdToStore = 'default.png';
    }

    $CredNew = new Client();
    $CredNew->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $CredNew->profession_id = $request->profession_id;
    $CredNew->nid_type = $request->nid_type;
    $CredNew->nid_photocopie = $IdToStore;
    $CredNew->image = $fileToStore;
    $CredNew->slug = $slug;
    $CredNew->save();

    return redirect(route('/bienvenue'));
    }
```

HERE MY ROUTES

```html
    //  ========= FINANCE - CLIENTS ======== //
    Route::get('/finance/creditor', [FinanceController::class,'indexCreditor'])
        ->name('finance.creditor');
    Route::post('/finance/store', [FinanceController::class,'store'])
        ->name('finance.store');
    Route::post('/finance/{id}/update', [FinanceController::class,'update'])
        ->name('finance.update');
    Route::delete('/finance/{id}/destroy', [FinanceController::class,'destroy'])
        ->name('finance.destroy');
```

HERE MY MODEL

```html
public function storeProfile(Request $request)
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Client extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $with = ['Userz'];

        protected $fillable = [
            'user_id',
            'profession_id',
            'nid_type',
            'nid_photocopie',
            'image',
            'slug'
        ];

        public function profesn()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Profession::class,'profession_id');
        }

        public function Userz()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
        }

        public function getRouteKeyName()
        {
            return 'slug';
        }
    }
```

HERE'S MY MIGRATIONS

```html
class CreateCreditorsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('profession_id');
            $table->string('nid_type');
            $table->string('nid_photocopie');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('slug')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: You have far too much code here, nobody is going to read through it all. You'll need to narrow down your problem, I'd start by using the browser's network inspector.

Comment: Your code is working correctly here. Try to see when you click the submit button, if there's any JavaScript errors in the console

Comment: does your data go up to the controller? I think there might have a problem with the submission of the form. are you using the javascript function or just directly using PHP to submit?

Comment: @Koussay i've successfully fixed all the javascript errors in the console BUT nothing happens

Comment: @TanvirUlHaque am using PHP to submit. Javascript functions present in that form are just for displaying images in the form when i select them from my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `dd()`, I was able to see which input field was causing the popup modal not to submit the data. Thanks for everyone who reached out!

```
dd($CredNew);
```